# Android Display over 1 mb pdf file inside a layout

Tags: java, android, html

I am trying to show a high quality pdf over 1 mb size inside a android layout .. I tried the 2 following methods:-
1) Using google docs viewer in webview
2) using jblough pdf library

In 1st method the color of the pdf not coming proper and the quality is not like we open in web browser.

In 2nd methods pdf files above 512 KB is not working properly and coming corrupted on the layout.

Any help will be appreciated thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this library and see if it works for you: http://joanzapata.com/android-pdfview/

**Sample Codes:**

Include PDFView in your layout:

```
<com.joanzapata.pdfview.PDFView
        android:id="@+id/pdfview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Load a PDF file:

```
pdfView.fromAsset(pdfName)
    .pages(0, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3)
    .defaultPage(1)
    .showMinimap(false)
    .enableSwipe(true)
    .onDraw(onDrawListener)
    .onLoad(onLoadCompleteListener)
    .onPageChange(onPageChangeListener)
    .load();
```

Comment: I tried including this library to my project and getting a lot of errors in the library related to package name.. what should i do?